# Implicit function theorem for operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, elliptic-pde, pseudo-differential-operators

Let $P: (-a,a) \rightarrow \Psi_h^0(\mathbb{R}),$ be a pseudodifferential operator in Weyl quantization with $(-a,a) \ni z \mapsto P(z)$ depending smoothly on this parameter $z$. Note that this parameter is not the semiclassical parameter which is $h$.

Moreover, $P$ is supposed to be self-ajoint, of principal type, elliptic and satisfy $\partial_z p(z)\le -C<0$ bounded away by some constant. Here $p$ is the symbol of $P.$

Then, in the link it is claimed that we can write $P(z)= A^*(z)(P-z)A(z)$ where $P,A \in \Psi_h^0(\mathbb{R}):$

[click me.](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ezworski/qmr.pdf)

In other words, what is claimed here is that by an application of the implicit function theorem and some iteration we can transform any PDO that may depend non-linearly on $z$ into a form that depends on $z$ in the trivial way $P-z.$

What I understand so far is that the condition $\partial_zp(x,\xi,z)<0$ allows us to apply the implicit function theorem, i.e. we get that $$p(x,\xi,z)=g(x,\xi,z)(h(x,\xi)-z)$$

for some local functions $h,g.$

But I am not really sure what kind of iteration may be meant here? Which kind of symbolic iteration allows us to go from this equation to the identity above. Apparently $P$ is the symbol associated with $h$ but how do we construct $A$?

In other words, does anybody understand how those operators $A$ and $P$ are constructed then?

If you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: Can you find a squre root of $P(z)$ under the conditions given? If the answer is yes, then $Q(z)=P(z)^{1/2}$ should be able to be factorized into something similar to $E(I-R)$, with $R$ a smoothing operator, and the theorem then follows.

Comment: I guess $g$ is positive and real, therefore $p(z) = g(z)^{1/2} (h - z) g(z)^{1/2}$ is the principal symbol of $A(z)^* (P - z) A(z)$ if $g(z)^{1/2}$ is the principal symbol of $A(z)$. Now use the usual iteration to get an error $O(h^\infty)$.